# Java how to remove last numbers of a long?

Tags: java, timestamp, long-integer

i'm working with a query to bring data acording to a given time. so i want to grab a timestamp an remove the last 3 digits of it. Is it possible? how? give me a hint i will totally apreciate that

Comment: Diego answer just what i needed, but, i will check the changing format solution as well, thanks to all!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to REMOVE the digits, divide by 10^n:

```
long x = 1234567890L;

long removeLastNDigits(long x, long n) {
  return x / Math.pow(10, n);
}

removeLastNDigits(x, 3) == 1234567L;
```

As pointed out by dasblinkenlight, if you want to 0 the last n digits then after removing them you need to add them back as 0:

```
long x = 1234567890L;

long zeroLastNDigits(long x, long n) {
  long tenToTheN = Math.pow(10, n);
  return (x / tenToTheN) * tenToTheN;
}

zeroLastNDigits(x, 3) == 1234567000L;
```

Comment: This would literally remove the three digits instead of zeroing them out, so the timestamp will no longer represent the time that it used to represent before. I think OP wants the same timestamp, but without milliseconds.

Comment: Make sense, took the question too literally. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer that i was looking for

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove the last 3 digits, just divide by 1000 :

```
long l = ...;
l = l / 1000;
```

If you want to change the last 3 digits to 0, divide by 1000 and then multiple by 1000 :

```
long l = ...;
l = (l / 1000) * 1000;
```

Answer (score 2):

just divide by 1000.

```
long x = 123456789L;
long withoutLast3 = x / 1000; // equals to 123456L
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should format your timestamp value according to the required format in the database, if that is what you are looking for that is fetching data based on date in a certain format.

You can format your date according based on a dateformatter and then use it in query.

Check

```
DateFormat
SimpleDateFormat
```